# Arranging tag elemenets with Sax in a XML file

Tags: java, sax

I want to construct this XML file:

```
<root>
<data>
<track src="123456">
<desc id="1" mt="audio/mp3" ra="24" dr="221" nv="10005761">
Madonna - La Isla Bonita
</desc>
<clipdata>PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlb</clipdata>
</track>
</data>
<completed/>
</root
```

This is some part of the code:

```
this.xml.startElement("", "", Const.XML_ROOT, atts);
            this.xml.startElement("", "", Const.XML_DATA, atts);
            atts.clear();

            atts.addAttribute("", "", "src", Const.XML_CDATA, "123456");
            this.xml.startElement("", "", Const.XML_TRACK, atts);

            atts2.addAttribute("", "", "id", Const.XML_CDATA, "1");
            atts2.addAttribute("", "", "mt", Const.XML_CDATA, "audio/mp3");
            atts2.addAttribute("", "", "ra", Const.XML_CDATA, "24");
            atts2.addAttribute("", "", "dr", Const.XML_CDATA, "221");
            atts2.addAttribute("", "", "nv", Const.XML_CDATA, "10005761");

            this.xml.startElement("", "", "desc", atts2);
            addCharacters(attsEmpty, "desc", "Madonna - La Isla Bonita");
            this.xml.endElement("", "", "desc");

            addCharacters(attsEmpty, "clipdata", "PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlb");

            this.xml.endElement("", "", Const.XML_TRACK);

            this.xml.endElement("", "", Const.XML_DATA);

            addCompleted();

            this.xml.endElement("", "", Const.XML_ROOT);
```

My problem is that I get this( I don't want the song to apear inside another desc /desc). What should I need to change to get the correct XML ? Thanks.

```
<root>
<data>
<track src="123456">
<desc id="1" mt="audio/mp3" ra="24" dr="221" nv="10005761">
<desc>Madonna - La Isla Bonita</desc>
</desc>
<clipdata>PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlb</clipdata>
</track>
</data>
<completed/>
</root>
```

Comment: Your code fragment has no context.  What is `this.xml`?  What is `addCharacters`?  What is `attrs`?  What is `addCompleted`?

Comment: yes i know that, I was expecting an answer that will tell me the order of my declarations, I guess that is the problem, or ? Thats way I didnt explain them

Comment: We can't tell what your code means without knowing what those things do.

Comment: Well, this.xml is where I redefined startElement(), endElement() Sax functions, addCompleted is a function to add the "completed" tag, attrs is on object of AttributeImpl

Comment: this is pretty confusing. skaffman is right, there's not enough information here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I had another startElement(desc) inside my addCharacters() function, that was causing the duplicate "desc" tag

Comment: Which is why I wanted to see the content of `addCharacters`....

Comment: Sorry, I was quite secure that wasn't the problem. Can you post the answer as well, so I can vote & accept ?